# signed in user session persists and dont sign in to Azure AD B2C with different email(mentioned in invitation url)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

i have a relying party application(web application) registered in AAD B2C and i am inviting the users to my groups in my tenant, for that, i sent the invitation url to them and user signup/sign in and enter in my application.
this process works perfectly if i test this flow in incognito window, but it saves my (inviter) credentials and on even clicking the invitation link this link dont sign up with the email mentioned in invitation rather it signs in with the already signed in(inviter) account.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser’s cache and cookies?

Comment: no i have not tried this, can you please tell how to do it in C# asp.net core application as my website is build using this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior. When a user successfully authenticates with a local or social account, Azure AD B2C stores a cookie-based session on the user's browser.

It is not expected that the invitee will be using the same browser as the inviter.

You do however have some options in configuring session behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior

For instance you can disable KMSI so that a persistent cookie will not be saved in the browser. That means users have to login every time the browser is restarted. But it resolves your problem. In any case, you should work under the assumption that invitees will open the invite link on their own machines with their own browsers.

Comment: yes yor are right that its not natural to be invitee and inviter be on same machine, but in my scenerio there is possibility that the inviter invites him self to another group within the application,then the inviter is invitee also in that case.